# Textbox readonly property makes whole group readonly during implementation of datatime picker

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying implement bootstrap datetime picket in my asp.net application. I have written the following code to display the datetime picker.

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datetimepicker1">   
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTime" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Date Time" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
<span class="input-group-addon">    
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
<span>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
</span>
</span>
</div>
```

I want to make the textbox, i.e., `#txtDateTime` readonly because I want to avoid validation regarding date and time. But when I make readonly property "True", everything becomes read only including the `<span>` that contain `glyphicon glyphicon-calendar`. How can I make only the `textbox` readonly.

Thanks
Partha

Comment: I am not sure that's an Issue to be fair.`span` element is actually an readonly element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean in read only span, anyway you can override `onkeydown` event on the input control this will be a safe solution not related to server side control like your solution.

```
<input onkeydown="return false"  />
```

In your example try this :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTime" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Date Time" onkeydown="return false"></asp:TextBox>
```